# Calc pie chart for 25000 rows with long tail

Tags: charts, libreoffice, openoffice, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I have a file that contains **25,000 rows**, each row containing a number, looking like this:

```
4000
3000
1500
700
...
2
1
1
1
```

From this I want to make a **pie chart**.

The first few pie parts will be clearly visible (ideally with labels), and the **long tail** (the last 90% of the values are very small) will form an indistinct area that **must have no labels**, because showing that many labels would take the whole page.

How to create such a pie chart with LibreOffice (or OpenOffice) Calc?

When I use the normal pie chart with default options Calc becomes ultra-slow before crashing (Ubuntu 2018.04)

Comment: I'm pretty sure, showing that many labels would take several pages if you wanted them to be at all legible.

Comment: I think it's illegal to create a pie chart with 25,000 slices.  :-)

Comment: If you have 25,000 rows, then the long tails items amount to less that one arc-minute (1/60 of a degree). Unless your pie chart is truly of humongus proportion, there is no way this will show up. You would be better off merging them into a "misc." category.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad: Each will not show up, of course, but little by little they form about half of the pie. Grouping everything below 13 (for instance) into a "misc" category would arbitrary, harder to grasp, and introduce Calc complexity (one more parameter to keep in mind when adding new data).

Comment: 1) You have a problem generating the chart, 2) it will result in a slice of a single homogenous colour (grey) once your reach a tail ±100 items long 3) To put it in perspective, if your chart is 10 *meters* in diameter, a slice of `1` will me ±1 mm wide at the edge. 4) the obvious solution is to concatenate small values into a single category -- a table with the data to display can be generated with a formula --  so no need to take any additional parameter into account. when adding data

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Your point "2" is exactly what I want :-)

Comment: You make the chart the same way you would with a reasonable amount of data. But yes, that amount of data will take some RAM and a bit of processing time. Does it actually crash or just hang? I tried it just for laughs and it locks up the computer for awhile. Some version of cybernetic.nomad's answer will be required if your computer can't handle the task. At some point, the slices won't be distinguishable, and you will end up with a solid gray slice, anyway. Figure out the smallest value that gives you a distinguishable slice, and make everything smaller a residual slice; it'll look the same.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's computer lacks the processing power to handle this many slices.  At some small number value, slices will become indistinguishable and create essentially a solid-looking slice.  So as a practical matter, crunching all 25,000 values doesn't really buy anything.  You can achieve the same result by finding the smallest value that is distinguishable and making that the last discrete value, then aggregating everything smaller into a residual slice.

That can be done by trial and error.  Use a variable to select the smallest size, and plot it.  Make the variable successively smaller until slices that size are no longer distinguishable.  Here's a way to do that:

1. Pick a starting cutoff value and stick it in E1.  For this example, the value is 13.  When you see the size of the resulting slice, that will give you an idea of how much to adjust it for the next iteration.
2. Assuming your data is in columns `A` and `B`, sorted in descending order (as in your example) enter the following formula in `E2`:

   =B2
3. Enter the following formula in `E3` and populate down until it returns empty cells:

   =IF(B2 < $E$1,"",IF(B3 >= $E$1,B3,SUM(B$2:B$25000)-SUM(E$2:E2)))
4. Enter the following formula in `D2` and populate down:

   =IF(E2 = "","",IF(B2=E2,A2,"Misc."))

You should now have something that looks like this:

[image]

Which will then allow you to generate a chart looking like this:

[image]

"Rinse and repeat", adjusting the cutoff value in E1 until smaller values don't contribute anything visible.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, they *are* an improvement. Note that in comments, OP says "Your point "2" is exactly what I want " in response to "2) it will result in a slice of a single homogenous colour (grey) once your reach a tail ±100 items long" -- so rthat's what I decided to respond to even though there *is* a contradiction between OP's statements... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯